# Hadoop append to Sequencefile

Tags: java, hadoop, sequencefile

Currently I use the following code to append to an existing *SequenceFile*:

```
// initialize sequence writer
Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(
        FileContext.getFileContext(this.conf), 
        this.conf, 
        new Path("/tmp/sequencefile"), 
        Text.class,
        BytesWritable.class, 
        CompressionType.NONE,
        null, 
        new Metadata(),
        EnumSet.of(CreateFlag.CREATE, CreateFlag.APPEND), 
        CreateOpts.blockSize(64 * 1024 * 1024));

writer.append(key, value);

// close writer
writer.hsync();
writer.close();
```

Everything works if the sequencefile not exists, but when the file exists Hadoop write the *SequenceFile* header (SEQ ...) again in the middle of the file and the file is unreadble for Hadoop.

I use Hadoop 2.6.0

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is not possible to append to existing sequence file. I've analyzed the source code of 2.5.2 and 2.6.0-CDH5.5. In every constructor of Writer "Sequence file header" is written (from the init function).

There is path to support this feature https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7139 but it is not pushed to oficial release.

UPDATE:
The issue HADOOP-7139 now is closed and from version 2.6.1 / 2.7.2 It's possible to append to an existing SequenceFile :)